# Excel: Force "Get data from web" web scrapper to use the exact url

Tags: microsoft-excel, website, import, microsoft-office-2016

I am trying to use Microsoft Excels built-in web scrapper (Data ribbon > Get data from web) to get some data from the website which address looks like this: "website.com/data/456/" but the excel tries to get the desired data from "website.com/data/456" (the "/" is missing from the end of the url) which redirects to a 404 error page. Is there any way to force Microsoft Excels built-in web scrapper to get data from the correct url (with "/" at the end of the address)?

I am using Microsoft Office 2016 64bit edition.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the site http://www.website.com/data/456/ is not available even if you write / at the end it gives:
HTTP 404 - File not found

The page you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Even if you try without Excel just by browsing the internet
Also you can write / after the address manually